# Mostrar promedios de notas de estudiantes en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

En la imagen, las calificaciones las muestra hacia abajo y me repite el nombre de la materia, he intentado de todo pero no logro que me solo me ponga una vez el nombre, y que me aparezcan hacia la derecha. Cada nota corresponde al periodo 1, 2 y 3.

[image: En la imagen, las calificaciones las muestra hacia abajo y me repite el nombre de la materia, he intentado de todo pero no logro que me solo me ponga una vez el nombre, y que me aparezcan hacia la derecha. Cada nota corresponde al periodo 1 2 y 3.]

---

Cuando doy clic sobre la calificación, me muestra correctamente las notas de cada evaluación.

[image: Cuando doy clic sobre la calificación, me muestra correctamente las notas de cada evaluacion.]

---

Mi pregunta es, como podria hacer para que solo me aparezca una vez la materia y las notas en el Td correspondiente. Muchas gracias. Dejo a continuacion el código.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

https://pastebin.com/AYT6DLLh

Comment: podrías subir una imagen de la DB para ver los campos de la tabla que estás trabajando?

Comment: de cuales tablas?

Comment: todas las que estén relacionadas con lo que muestras.